# Writing an array of integers to a text file vertically(each element of the array should be written on a new line in the file) in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file-handling

How do I write an array of numbers to a text file and read the numbers later from the text file to the console in c#?

The following code just writes the last element of the array to the txt file.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string inttostr;
    int[] stringArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    for(int i = 0; i< stringArray.Length; i++)
    {
      inttostr = stringArray[i].ToString();
      File.WriteAllText("new.txt", inttostr);
    }

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("new.txt"))
    {
        
        string res = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you start your troubleshooting effort reading the documentation of [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-7.0). Your problems is explained in the first two lines. And while you are on that site look also for the method File.WriteAllLines

Answer (score 1):

If you would use WriteAll* then WriteAllLines is better:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] stringArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    File.WriteAllLines("new.txt", stringArray.Select(x => x.ToString()));
    
    string res = File.ReadAllText("new.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one-liner really.

```
int[] stringArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
File.WriteAllText("stringArray.txt", string.Join(Envirnoment.NewLine, stringArray));
```